# Is there an upper bound on Bell numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

For some reason my intuition is that $n^n$ might be an upper bound for Bell numbers, but I can't find anything to confirm that.

Sorry if this is a simple question! (it's been a while since my undergrad math days)

Comment: I recommend you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: See the bounds and asymptotic formulas [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Growth_rate).

Comment: Well that's embarrassing :) just went back to the wikipedia page and found this right before you guys commented. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $n^n$ is an upper bound, and in fact a more precise tighter one exists:

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Growth_rate

Answer (score 0):

"For some reason my intuition is that $n^n$ might be an upper bound for Bell numbers" - here is a simple way to confirm the intuition.

The Bell number $B_n$ is the number of ways to partition the set $\{1,..,n\}$.

The number of maps from $\{1,..,n\}$ to $\{1,..,n\}$ is precisely $n^n$ (there are $n$ ways to map $1\in\{1,..,n\}$, $n$ ways to map $2$, ... , $n$ ways to map $n$, so altogether this gives $n\cdot n\cdot  ...  \cdot n = n^n$). Now, each such map $f$ defines a partition of $\{1,..,n\}$: i and j are in the same partition element if $f(i)=f(j)$.

Moreover, for any given partition $P$ of $\{1,..,n\}$ there exists a corresponding map $f_P$. Indeed it suffices to enumerate the elements of the partition and to map each $i\in\{1,..,n\}$ to the number of the partition element to which $i$ belongs.

So the number of the partitions of $\{1,..,n\}$, which is the Bell number $B_n$, is less or equal to the number of maps from $\{1,..,n\}$ to $\{1,..,n\}$, which is $n^n$.

Remark: the above correspondence between partitions and functions is not one to one. Indeed, two different maps may correspond to the same partition: take $n=2$ and the maps $f_1,f_2$ where $f_1(0)=0, f_1(1)=1$ and $f_2(0)=1, f_2(1)=0$. Both define the same partition.